# How to redirect a WordPress request for an upload to an external URL?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a link out in the wild that points to a PDF uploaded to my site. Instead of serving the PDF (which is no longer there, btw), I want people to be sent to a YouTube video. I've tried something like this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "Case-Study\.pdf$" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" [R=301,L]
```

This works when the URL is `https://example.com/Case-Study.pdf`, but not when it's `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Case-Study.pdf`. The latter, of course, being the URL needed to be redirected.

The rest of the .htaccess file looks like so:

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "Case-Study\.pdf$" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/contact$ https://example.com/#contact [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

php_value post_max_size          128M
php_value upload_max_filesize     64M
# END WordPress
```

So, why isn't my RewriteRule working? (Thanks for your help.)

Comment: .htaccess is in the root. But I could easily add one in the uploads directory.

Comment: @anubhava tried it, and still getting 404.

Comment: @anubhava How could a plugin bypass .htaccess? .htaccess would be processed by Apache before passing the request to PHP, no?

Comment: OK, a colleague figured it out: because the target file was no longer there (had been renamed), Apache returned the 404 without running through mod_rewrite. This, apparently, is configurable in Apache (not certain how), and would explain why I got it working locally, but couldn't get past it on the production server. Thanks for yr help.

Comment: The Apache configuration issue has to do with MultiViews and mod_negotiate. See https://www.systemcodegeeks.com/web-servers/apache/apache-multiviews-mod_rewrite/.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out mod-rewrite can be subverted by another module: mod_negotiation. If you use negotiation's MultiViews option, it can return a 404 for a missing file BEFORE it goes to mod_rewrite.

So the RewriteRule above works with a file that's there; or works with a file that's not there, but on a server that does NOT have MultiViews enabled.

Explained more fully here: https://www.systemcodegeeks.com/web-servers/apache/apache-multiviews-mod_rewrite/